# Show value from returned id on an api request, when this value and id lives on a json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting info from an API. Between the returned data, i have one id of 'x' value, whitch it's contained on a json file.

This is the code of the api:

```
function listData (){
   $http.get('api/Example')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.list = data.data.Response;
        //console.log($scope.list);
    });
}
```

The mentioned value returned is: `IdFruit`. This Id have relationship with the values on the next json:

```
[
 {
  "Id": 1,
  "value": "Apple"
  },
  {
  "Id": 2,
  "value": "Pear"
  },
  {
  "Id": 3,
  "value": "Mango"
  }
  ]
```

And the code to consume the json is:

```
function comboFruit (){
     $http.get('/fruits.json')
     .then(function(data){
        $scope.getFruits = data.data;
        //console.log($scope.getFruits);
     });
    }
```

What i want to do, is to show on my html view the `value` of the fruit instead of the `Id`. How can i do that, if i just get the mentioned id of the fruit on the api? I've modify my first code to print on the console the value, and it works:

```
function listData (){
       $http.get('api/Example')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.list = data.data.Response;
            //console.log($scope.list);
                for(var i = 0; i< $scope.list.length; i++){
                    for(var j = 0; j< $scope.getFruits.length; j++){
                        if($scope.list[i].IdFruit === $scope.getFruits[j].Id){
                            $scope.valueType = $scope.getFruits[j].value;
                            //console.log($scope.valueType);
                        }
                    }
                };
        })
    }
```

My problem is to show the `$scope.valueType` on the html if i'm using ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in list">
                <th>{{info.IdFruit}}</th>
```

How can i do that?

Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You should clean up some of your code and your question. Where did IdFruit come from? The JSON only contains id as one of the property names. Should it be idFruit or IdFruit? If your problem is to print valueType, why don't you just print it?

Comment: IdFruit comes on the api response. Just the id, and it have relationship with the json. My problem is how to show the value of that Id on the api response, if i'm using ng-repeat. Sorry, i have too much to learn yet from angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you are getting the `IdFruit` from one API call and the `value` from another. What you can do is create an array of objects to hold the pairs.

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array

dict.push({
    key:   "keyName",
    value: "the value"
});
```

So before/in your `for` loop

```
var Controller = function($scope) { 
    $scope.pairs = [];
...
}
...
...

for(var i = 0; i< $scope.list.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j< $scope.getFruits.length; j++){
        if($scope.list[i].IdFruit === $scope.getFruits[j].Id){
            $scope.valueType = $scope.getFruits[j].value;
            $scope.pairs.push({
                key: $scope.list[i].idFruit, // Can use $scope.getFruits[j].Id since ids are the same
                value: scope.getFruits[j].value
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Now in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="fruit in pairs">
    <th>{{fruit.id}}</th> <!-- Only meant to show that you have the pairs now -->
    <th>{{fruit.value}}</th>
```

Comment: Wow! I tried too and it works! Thanx for another elegant example :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 function listData (){
           $http.get('api/Example')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.list = data.data.Response;
                //console.log($scope.list);
                    for(var i = 0; i< $scope.list.length; i++){
                        for(var j = 0; j< $scope.getFruits.length; j++){
                            if($scope.list[i].IdFruit === $scope.getFruits[j].Id){
                                $scope.list[i].value = $scope.getFruits[j].value;
                            }
                        }
                    };
            })
        }
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in list">
                <th>{{info.value}}</th>
```